# How to condense this java program?

Tags: java

I'm trying to condense this code so its more leaner. I know there has to be a way to use the calculation from the past else if statement to use it in the next tax bracket calculation. I tried to put tax = ph in each else if statement to use in the next calculation (for place holder value) but it will just ignore it.
Edit: rewording this here to not sound like feedback. My code is too long how can I make it shorter? Also I have to use the switch statement in this assignment.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print(
  "(0-single filer, 1-married jointly or qualifying widow(er), "
  + "\n2-married separately, 3-head of household)\n" +
  "Enter the filing status: ");

int status = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the taxable income: ");
double income = input.nextDouble();
double tax = 0;



switch (status){
    case 0: {      // file single
       if (income <= 8350)
       tax = income * 0.10;
       else if (income <= 33950)
        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (income - 8350) * 0.15;
       else if (income <= 82250)
        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
        (income - 33950) * 0.25;
       else if (income <= 171550)
         tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
        (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (income - 82250) * 0.28;
       else if (income <= 372950)
         tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
         (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (171550 - 82250) * 0.28 +
         (income - 171550) * 0.33;
       else
         tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
         (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (171550 - 82250) * 0.28 +
         (372950 - 171550) * 0.33 + (income - 372950) * 0.35;
           }
    break;
    case 1:{      //file married or Widow  
        if (income <= 16700)
          tax = income * 0.10;
        else if(income <= 67900)
           tax = 16700 * .10 + (income - 16700) * .15;
        else if (income <= 137050)
            tax = 16700 * .10 + (67900 - 16700) * .15 + (income - 137050) * .25;
        else if (income <= 208850)
            tax = 16700 * .10 + (67900 - 16700) * .15 + (137050 - 67900) *  .25 + 
                    (income - 208850) * .28;
        else if (income <= 372950)
            tax = 16700 * .10 + (67900 - 16700) * .15 + (137050 - 67900)  * .25 + 
                    (208850 - 137050) * .28 + (income - 372950) * .33;
        else
            tax =  16700 * .10 + (67900 - 16700) * .15 + (137050 - 67900) * .25 + 
                    (208850 - 137050) * .28 + (372950 - 208850) * .33 + (income - 372950) * .35;
    }
    break;

}
System.out.println("Your tax will be $" + tax);


}
```

}

Comment: Can you not factor out all the hardcoded calculations into numbers.  Change this "8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
         (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (171550 - 82250) * 0.28 +
         (372950 - 171550) * 0.33" to whatever the result is.  That will help readability a lot.

Comment: @tom on the other hand, it will be bad for maintainability because it hides the formula behind the values.

Comment: then at least make them constants!

Comment: Take out all the blanks and carriage returns.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version has a minimum of condition checking at the expense of extra calculations, producing fairly concise code with and all the "magic" numbers easily visible in one place.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int income = 1000000;  // Sample test amount of income, should result in 327,683.50 in taxes.
    double tax = 0;
    if (income > 0) {
        tax = income * 0.10;
        tax += (Math.max(0, income-8350)) * 0.05;
        tax += (Math.max(0, income-33950)) * 0.10;
        tax += (Math.max(0, income-82250)) * 0.03;
        tax += (Math.max(0, income-171550)) * 0.05;
        tax += (Math.max(0, income-372950)) * 0.02;
    }
    System.out.println("Tax: "  + tax);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very barebones, I don't exactly know what "Math.max" does but I'll look into, cause it saves me sooooo much time!

Comment: Math.max selects the greatest number from the parameters passed.  Math.max(0, -7) would evaluate to 0.  This used to ensure you don't compute and then tax a negative amount.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, but you could incrementally increase "tax" and decrease "income".

For example :

```
tax = income * 0.10; // 10% you always pay
income = Math.max(0, income-8350); // Take away the first 8350, on which we already have 10% tas
tax += income * 0.05; // 5% more on income higher than 8350
income = Math.max(0, income-33950); // Take away 33950, on wich we already gave 5% more taxes
tax += income * 0.10; // 10% more on income higher than 33950
```

And so on.

Double check my math, i didn't explore all your ifs, but i used this way to compute taxes here.

Feel free to ask clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do (just showing a part of case 0):

```
tax = income * 0.10;
income -= 8350;
if (income > 0) {
    tax += income * (0.15 - 0.1);
    income -= 33950 - 8350;
}
if (income > 0) {
    tax += income * (0.25 - 0.15);
    income -= 82250 - 33950;
}
...
```

This also shows, how you could use a loop to do the calculations when you store the constants in two arrays.